# Does the SQL Server 2005 database size property include the full-text index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

The title pretty much says it all, but in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, if I look at the database properties and pick up the size value, will that include the full-text index data?

Does it include the log file as well?

Rough values are fine, but some of our ft indexes can be large, so I want to be sure of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in SQL Server 2005, the fulltext indices are external to SQL Server in the server's file system. I don't think those are included in the database size when you look at them in SQL Server Management Studio.

This is totally changed in SQL Server 2008 where the fulltext system has been fully integrated into the database core.

Answer (score 0):

Fulltext indexing in 2005 is saved on hard drive separated from .ldf and .mdf files, while file size limit you talking about is about database files themselves.